# Facebook comments plugin: sorting comments by default

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

By default the comments are shown by "social ranking".

Is it possible to set the default value to "reverse chronological"?

The official docs for social plugins does not mention this option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the social plugin given by FB, then i think there is no such option available..

what do u mean by Social ranking?

If you are ready to use FQL then you can try my below suggestion.

Normally all FB data are rendered based on timestamps , so if u want to get the latest comments for a specific page, you can use the FQL query to get desired results..

Sample query

```
http://www.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&pretty=1&method=fql.query&
query=select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where
object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where 
url ="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/") 
order by time desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Anyway i'm forced to use the plugin version. :(
By "social ranking" i mean that the comments are sorted by a social algorithm.

Comment: that's ok. In plugin version , facebook doesn't allow the users to customize more.. we should stick with what we have :(

Answer (score 2):

I answered here too: [Setting Facebook comments web plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481765/setting-facebook-comments-web-plugin/16203435?noredirect=1#comment23169644_16203435)

It just works if you add the attribute

```
data-order-by="reverse_time"
```

to the div provided in the html5 version provided by Facebook.

(sorry for the duplicate answer. I came across here googling, that's why I think is usefull to post it here too)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for exact duplicate, but **it is possible to set the default sorting order to reverse chronological**. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481765/setting-facebook-comments-web-plugin).