# Setting Facebook comments web plugin

Tags: facebook, sorting, plugins, facebook-fql

The default sorting order of the facebook comments plugin is *by social status*. How do I set the default order to *reverse chronological* on my web page?

I know there is an option on the top of the plugin. But not all users know about it and the sorting order is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing I added

```html
 data-order-by="reverse_time"
```

to the div provided by Facebook and it worked nicely. 
So, loading the pluging with the standard html5 code provided here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

just add the `data-order-by` attribute like this:

```html
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="YOUR_URL" data-width="470" data-num-posts="6" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. This worked even when setting the default in the moderation page did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I was googling a lot without success, so I solved this by some reverse engeneering...

1. Use some browser code inspector to see which iframe was inserted by facebook javascript that adds the comments plugin into the page. Copy the `facebook_crazy_url` of that iframe (see step 2). The inserted iframe seems to be the only thing that is needed to run the comments properly
2. Get rid of the FB javascript and insert your own iframe instead: set the url to "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?channel_url=`facebook_crazy_url`&**order_by=reverse_time**"

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work for me.  Anyone else get this to work?  Currently.

Comment: This only works for users that are logged out of FB. Go figure

Comment: @Jan: I've tried your solution on my site and it worked. I only have one observation: I couldn't get the height dynamically set according to the number of posts I set on the "num_posts" parameter. It works on the default Facebook SDK Javascript/HTML code, but not with this approach. Any thoughts?

Comment: @XpiritO: You can add your own javascript to adjust the iframe height to fit its contents, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525992/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height-in-it). But after clicking the *show more* link the height changes. To check the iframe every cca 50ms and adjust it again is the only solution I can imagine.

Answer (score 3):

Another option inspired by Jan Turoň's solution:

1. put your fb:comments in a div with id "comments":

```html
    <div id="comments"><fb:comments ...></fb:comments></div>
```

1. use jQuery to change the generated iframe's src:

```js
    $('#comments iframe').attr('src', $('#comments iframe').attr('src') + '&order_by=reverse_time')
```

Of course, you can do this without jQuery.

It loads the comments' frame twice, but it works in all cases without harcoding the iframe's src.

Comment: ...and the jQuery code needs to be placed AFTER the FB javascript (both codes are synchronous)

Comment: what does that "after th FB javascrip" means".
I tried to load js sdk synchronously and then put that line of jquery code at the end of the html page.  but it does not work

Comment: @Eddy Chan: The facebook javascript creates the iframe, Fabrices' jQuery code updates src of that iframe, so it has to be called AFTER the iframe is done.

Comment: I tried this and I could not get the results.  It is not ordering by reverse time.  It is only doing the stupid Social Ranking that does not help my users.  Is there anyone that is currently doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the default sort order of the comments plugin. To achieve something like this, you could retrieve the comments yourself, e.g., using FQL, but then you need to build everything else, too. Or use something like Disqus.

Comment: I just can't believe that such a famous plugin doesn't have such an elementary feature...

Comment: Well, the social plugins do not have a means of styling them with CSS anymore either -- even though that makes integrating them very difficult for many web site designs and many developers have expressed their dissatisfaction. Facebook wants us to use the "social relevance" sorting and they are enforcing it. It's sink or swim.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/{Your_app_id}/ and then click the Settings link, it will let you edit the "Sort Comments By" setting.

The choices are:

- Top
- Newest
- Oldest

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#moderation-setup-instructions, your webpage must have a tag like `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APP_ID}" />`.

P.S. Unfortunately for me, since I'm using ClickFunnels, adding this tag doesn't seem to have any effect. I would instead need to be in complete control of my webpage (and not use a simplified tool like ClickFunnels).